# Cytoscape. Load dependency from URL

Tags: html, github, cytoscape.js

This is a very simple question.
How can I indicate the cytoscape as a source via a url?
I know with `D3` it is very simple

```
 <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

What is the equivalent address for cytoscape?

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably ask a separate question if you continue to have problems getting the intro tutorial running, since it's a very different topic than your original question. That said, as a first guess - do you have a <div id="cy"></div> container in your html? That would cause the JS to display nothing.

Comment: @gbe understood. I will make a new question. No, that code is not included. Also what does CDN stand for?

Comment: You'll need some minimal html scaffolding in your file to set up things; the cytoscape tutorial assumes you know how to supply it. Most tutorials on running javascript should get you started. And CDN stands for content delivery network.

Comment: You mean: `<!DOCTYPE html><meta charset="utf-8"><html><head>stuff</head><body>stuff</body></html>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term you're looking for is a CDN-hosted copy of the code; strictly speaking, you're still using a URL even when you specify a local copy.

It looks like Cloudflare (a major CDN company) hosts copies of the code; a google search turned up [this index](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/cytoscape) which should help you find the correct links for the version you need.