# Loading and using JSON for Cytoscape.js

Tags: html, cytoscape.js

## Context

I want to use `cytoscape.js` for visualizing graphs. While I am capable with a myriad of languages (`C++`, `Mathematica`, `R`, etc), I am new to `Javascript`, `JSON`, `HTML`, and `CSS`. Thus it would be favorable to learn these languages through this use case (implementing graphs with `cytoscape.js`). Please keep this in mind in your answer.

I have previously asked how to [remotely load [`cytoscape.js`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40298582/5623899) and [how to get graphs display (requires a `div`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40299892/5623899). Since then I have created a script that turns a graph as represented in one of the other languages I use, into the `JSON` format indicated [here](http://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/elements-json). While I can just copy-paste all of this directly into my program, for large networks that is clearly a poor way to implement it. An example of my script's output is at the bottom of this.

## Question

Given a `JSON` object/file(?) how can I do the following:

- load it into `cytoscape.js` without copy-pasting the code.
- referencing it once loaded. (e.g. basic explanation of how JSON syntax for use in `cytoscape.js`)

## Script Output

```
cytoscape({

container: document.getElementById('cy'),

elements: [ 
{// node Node 1
    group: 'nodes',

    data: {
        id: 'Node 1'
    },

    selected: false,

    selectable: true,

    locked: false,

    grabbable: true,

    selectable: true,

},
{// node Node 2
    group: 'nodes',

    data: {
        id: 'Node 2'
    },

    selected: false,

    selectable: true,

    locked: false,

    grabbable: true,

    selectable: true,

},
{// node Node 3
    group: 'nodes',

    data: {
        id: 'Node 3'
    },

    selected: false,

    selectable: true,

    locked: false,

    grabbable: true,

    selectable: true,

},
{// edge 1_2
    group: 'edges',

    data: {
        id: '1_2',
        source: '1',
        target: '2'
    }
},
{// edge 2_3
    group: 'edges',

    data: {
        id: '2_3',
        source: '2',
        target: '3'
    }
},
{// edge 3_1
    group: 'edges',

    data: {
        id: '3_1',
        source: '3',
        target: '1'
    }
}
],
style: [
    {
        selector: 'node',
        style: {
            'content': 'data(id)'
        }
    }
]

});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/vendor/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
    #cy {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="cy"></div>
    <script>
        $.getJSON("cyto.js", function (data) {
            //console.log(data);
            var cy = cytoscape({
                container: document.getElementById('cy'),
                elements: data,
                style: [
                    {
                        selector: 'node',
                        style: {
                            'label': 'data(label)',
                            'width': '60px',
                            'height': '60px',
                            'color': 'blue',
                            'background-fit': 'contain',
                            'background-clip': 'none'
                        }
                    }, {
                        selector: 'edge',
                        style: {
                           'text-background-color': 'yellow',
                            'text-background-opacity': 0.4,
                            'width': '6px',
                            'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
                            'control-point-step-size': '140px'
                        }
                    }
                ],
                layout: {
                    name: 'circle'
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

in cyto.js you can input valid JSON data, for example

```
  {
    "nodes": [
            {
            "data": {"id": "a", "label": "Gene1"}
            },
            {
            "data": {"id": "b", "label": "Gene2"}
            },
            {
            "data": {"id": "c", "label": "Gene3"}
            },
            {
            "data": {"id": "d", "label": "Gene4"}
            },
            {
            "data": {"id": "e", "label": "Gene5"}
            },
            {
            "data": {"id": "f", "label": "Gene6"}
            }
    ],
            "edges": [
            {
            "data": {
            "id": "ab",
                    "source": "a",
                    "target": "b"
            }
            },
            {
            "data": {
            "id": "cd",
                    "source": "c",
                    "target": "d"
            }
            },
            {
            "data": {
            "id": "ef",
                    "source": "e",
                    "target": "f"
            }
            },
            {
            "data": {
            "id": "ac",
                    "source": "a",
                    "target": "d"
            }
            },
            {
            "data": {
             "id": "be",
                    "source": "b",
                    "target": "e"
                }
                }]    
    }
```

Comment: Neat example; run on webserver (e.g. `http-server`) to avoid CORS issue when running on local host.

Answer (score 0):

Let's presume you have a json file in the same folder as your 'index.html', and your server is running. First request the json file via a http request (using [plain javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) or [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706046/how-to-read-an-external-local-json-file-in-javascript) ).

If your json file has the same format as the `elements` properties, you can just parse it to a javascript object and set it. E.g.

```js
var myObject = {};
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myObject = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      initCytoscape();
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "myJson.json", true);
xhttp.send();

function initCytoscape() {
  cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    elements: myObject
  });
}
```

if the json property is different than cytoscape's format, then you have to programatically convert it.

Comment: I have a lot of  questions, but could you possibly walk me through how this works?

Comment: If you use the `fetch()` API, you can just specify `elements: fetch('./my-dir/myfile.json')`, since Cytoscape accepts promises for your data